# Using table type parameter together with regular parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'd like to insert some list into a SQL server table with some additional parameter. Something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AddChosenSecurities
    @ProjectID INT, 
    @Securities BusinessValuationSecurityTblType READONLY

AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TblBusinessValuationsSecurities @ProjectID, @Securities

END
```

`BusinessValuationSecurityTblType` is a table type parameter

How can I do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your second parameter is **table-valued** parameter, you need to **select from it** like from a regular table - something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AddChosenSecurities
    @ProjectID INT, 
    @Securities BusinessValuationSecurityTblType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TblBusinessValuationsSecurities 
        SELECT @ProjectID, Col1, Col2, Col3
        FROM @Securities
END
```

This assumes that you have `Col1, Col2, Col3` in your table-valued parameter, adapt as needed.
Side note: you should ***NEVER*** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!